# Unable to instantiate ng app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have the following app.js and its unable to invoke the app with modules. attached screenshot of folder structure and code:

core.module.js:

```css
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core');
})();
```

```css
(function () {
    'use strict';
   
    angular
        .module('app', [
            'ngRoute',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngResource',
            'ngCookies',
            'ngTouch',
            'app.core',
            'app.events'
        ])
        .config(config);
        
    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {..}..
```

```css
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.core' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need the second param on `angular.module()`;

See [Document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

> // Create a new module
>
> var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

```
angular
    .module('app.core',[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. angular.module('app.core', []) is to create a new module without any module dependency.
2. angular.module('app.core') is to retrieve an existing module whose name is app.core.

So to create angular module, you will have to write angular.module('app.core', []).

Comment: I have done that now, still it gives me same error and also, updated screenshot for which it says - unknown provider ServiceFactory!